# mount cifs: How split in multiple lines the values of the o parameter?

Tags: mount, cifs

The following command works:

```
sudo mount -t cifs //192.168.1.77/something /mnt/192.168.1.77/something \
           -o username=alpha,rw,uid=alpha,gid=tango,dir_mode=0770,file_mode=0770,nounix,sec=ntlmssp
```

Observe is possible split the long command in two lines thanks to `\`.

But for presentation purposes of the command itself, if I try now to split the parameters of the `-o` parameter again with `\` - it is not possible, it arises an error, it because exists empty spaces. Well I deleted all the empty spaces, but in some place they are added.

Is possible accomplish this goal? How?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply specify `-o` multiple times, e.g. `-o opt1,opt2 -o opt3,opt4` and then use  `\` to break them into more lines.